PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
I've been working on projecting raster files to a new coordinate reference system (CRS) for various datasets. However, I just encountered some warning messages that I haven't seen before. While the next step in my pipeline seems unaffected, I'm still a little concerned about potential implications downstream. Could anyone shed light on what might be the cause of these warnings and their potential implications?
library(sf)
library(terra)

PET <- rast(x = 'Global-AI_ET0_v3_annual/et0_v3_yr.tif')
PETESRI54017 <- project(PET, 'ESRI:54017')
warnings()


There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Warning messages:
1: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
2: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
3: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
4: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
5: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
6: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
7: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
8: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
9: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
10: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
11: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
12: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
13: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
14: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
15: PROJ: cea: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)


https://epsg.io/54017 doesn't use units of latitude and longitude

I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand the idea. I've projected other datasets to ESRI:54017 as well, all from 'EPSG:4326' to 'ESRI:54017', and no warnings have appeared until this particular dataset, 'Global-AI_ET0_v3_annual/et0_v3_yr.tif'.
